# Meaning of " in the wings "

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

The following passage is from the book The Demonologist: The Extraordinary Career of Ed and Lorraine Warren:

> Yet, when you have a case
> involving fire; the teleportation of
> anvils, doors, and radiator covers; the
> levitation of extremely heavy objects;
> the sacrilegious movement of rosary
> beads and blessed statues; plus,irrational, almost berserk instances of
> blasphemy-—then it’s certain there’s a
> true maniac **in the wings** orchestrating
> the pandemonium.

I've searched for this phrase and I only found "on the wings"
Which means active and in motion , are these phrases the same ? Or maybe different meanings?

Comment: ["in the wings"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+the+wings%22+meaning&sxsrf=APwXEdehOT9qZjpkU4v8DDslpMQVF4p7Qw%3A1684692150804&ei=tlxqZLnWMJ2sxc8Pz8e70AQ&ved=0ahUKEwi5idGp_4b_AhUdVvEDHc_jDkoQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22in+the+wings%22+meaning&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCAAQgAQyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIICAAQFhAeEA8yBggAEBYQHjIICAAQFhAeEA8yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgoIABBHENYEELADOgsILhCKBRDUAhCRAjoICC4QigUQkQI6CAguEIAEENQCOhkILhCKBRDUAhCRAhCXBRDcBBDeBBDgBBgBOgUILhCABDoICAAQigUQhgNKBAhBGABQrghYsxxgyiFoAXABeACAAXSIAYMGkgEDNy4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB2gEGCAEQARgU&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wings](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wing) here refers metaphorically to:

> In a theatre, the wings are the sides of the stage which are hidden from the audience by curtains or scenery.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

So in the wings here refers to a place where one cannot be seen, secretly.

Comment: I'll note that "wings" are often used to refer to sections of a building that branch off from the central structure, without any direct association with theatre buildings.  Some of these usages may be derived from the theatre paradigm, but others likely are not.

Answer (score 3):

"In the wings" comes from theatre.  The "wings" are off-stage so the audience does not see who is there.  But the director of the production could be there, controlling what happens on the stage.